# How to use the h function in Vue3 to complete the binding/passing of properties/events between parent and child components?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue3 and naive ui to develop the front-end, but I am mainly a back-end developer and I don’t know much about the front-end.

I use naive ui’s `BasicTable` to add an `Edit button` for each row of data in the list, and by clicking the Edit button, a dialog box pops up, where I can complete the modification of the current row record, and click OK to send the modified data to the back-end to complete the revision.

In naive ui, dialogs are created by useDialog().create(), while normal dialogs are directly displayed as components and have no pop-up effect, so I can only use the default useDialog method.

In this way, if I want to customize the form in the dialog, I have to use the `render function h`. I use the h function to create a subcomponent, like this:

```
  function handleEdit(record: Recordable) {
    currentRecord.value = record;
    const dialogIns = dialog.create({
      title: 'edit User',
      content: () => {
        return h(EditEmployee, {
          source: currentRecord.value,
          on: {
            updateEmployee: (value) => {
              console.log(`emit Value is ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
              dialogIns.destroy();
            },
            cancelUpdate: () => {
              console.log('cancel');
              dialogIns.destroy();
            },
          },
        });
      },
      // positiveText: 'Submit',
      // negativeText: 'Cancel',
      // onPositiveClick: () => {},
      // onNegativeClick: () => {},
    });
  }
```

Next, I defined my subcomponent, which is simply `a form and two buttons`. The two buttons represent submit and cancel, respectively.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <n-form :model="editEmployee">
      <n-form-item label="Id">
        <n-input v-model:value="editEmployee.eid" disabled />
      </n-form-item>
      <n-form-item label="Name">
        <n-input v-model:value="editEmployee.empName" />
      </n-form-item>
      <n-form-item label="Identity">
        <n-input v-model:value="editEmployee.sysId" />
      </n-form-item>
      <n-form-item label="InGroupId">
        <n-input v-model:value="editEmployee.inGroupId" />
      </n-form-item>
      <n-grid :cols="24">
        <n-gi :span="16"></n-gi>
        <n-gi :span="4">
          <n-button type="info" @click="handleUpdate"> Submit</n-button>
        </n-gi>
        <n-gi :span="4">
          <n-button type="tertiary" @click="handleCancel">Cancel</n-button>
        </n-gi>
      </n-grid>
    </n-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { computed, ref } from 'vue';

  const emit = defineEmits(['updateEmployee', 'cancelUpdate']);

  const source_data = defineProps<{
    source: {
      eid: number;
      sysId: string | null;
      empName: string | null;
      inGroupId: string | null;
    };
  }>();

  const editEmployee = ref({ ...source_data.source });

  function handleUpdate() {
    console.log(`update Event for param ${JSON.stringify(editEmployee.value)}`);
    emit('updateEmployee', editEmployee.value);
  }

  function handleCancel() {
    emit('cancelUpdate');
  }
</script>

<style lang="less" scoped></style>
```

Submitting gets the current form data and then emits it to the parent component, which updates the data (because in naive ui’s dialog component, submit and cancel are controlled by the parent component `(onPositiveClick, onNegativeClick)`, and the subcomponent cannot give the new data to the parent component without any buttons, so the subcomponent must actively send it to the parent component (at least it needs to submit a close dialog event to the parent component)).

But after I defined it, I found that the emit method of the subcomponent would not be received by the parent component at all. I tried many methods, but they all failed.

So, my question is how to make the parent component receive the emit event from the subcomponent, because when I actually debugged in the browser, I found that the console.log method in the subcomponent was triggered, but after emitting, the parent component could not receive it. I want to know what’s going on.

Comment: A workable demo will seriously help your case because at this point this is something that's probably can't be solved on paper and needs to be debugged. Not sure if it really requires the use of render functions, most times you can avoid them with the proper use of templates, slots, etc. "after emitting, the parent component could not receive it" - you can properly debug this in vue devtools, the events are shown there. I doubt about `on:` in render function, afaik this doesn't work or at least not guaranteed, use `onUpdateEmployee`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in parent component and create a props in child component with Function type then pass function from parent to child and call its in the child component.
in parent component

```
<script setup>

function updateEmployee(value) {
   console.log(value)
}
     
 

dialog.create({ 
   content: () => h(EditEmployee, {
      onUpdateEmployee: updateEmployee
     })
  })
</script>
```

in child component

```
<template>
 <button @click="onUpdateEmployee(value)">update</button>
</template>

<script setup>
  const props = defineProps({
   onUpdateEmployee: {
      type: Function,
      required: true,
   }
})
</script>
```